# Python dict key is auto-converting to byte object?

Tags: python

I am trying to interact with an API.

I put my token into  key but python auto convert str to byte object.

Target Function:

```
def spam_event(channel_id, auth_token, message, delay):
    print(auth_token)                                                      print(type(auth_token))
    url = f"https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{channel_id}/messages"
    headers = {
            "authorization" : auth_token,
            "user-agent" : "Discord Android",
            "connection" : "keep-alive"
            }
    data = {
            "content" : message
            }
    while True:
        time.sleep(delay)
        message_send_requests = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
```

Root Function:

```
def spam_menu_event():                                                     clear_terminal_event()
    print(fade.brazil(zirinus))
    message = str(input("Message: "))
    while True:
        try:
            delay = float(input("Delay: "))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Must be a number!")
    print("Starting...")
    try:
        with open("tokens.txt", "r") as token_file:
            auth_token = token_file.read()
        with open("channel_ids.txt", "r") as channel_id_file:
            channel_id = channel_id_file.read()
    except Exception as e:
        print("tokens.txt and channel_ids.txt files not found!")
        print(e)
        sys.exit()
    spam_event(channel_id, auth_token, message, delay)
```

Output:

```
Message: test
Delay: 1
Starting...
exampletoken123

<class 'str'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/projelerim/zirinus-rewrite/main.py", line 217, in <module>
    main_event()
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/projelerim/zirinus-rewrite/main.py", line 202, in main_event
    main_menu_event()
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/projelerim/zirinus-rewrite/main.py", line 170, in main_menu_event
    spam_menu_event()
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/projelerim/zirinus-rewrite/main.py", line 154, in spam_menu_event
    spam_event(channel_id, auth_token, message, delay)
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/projelerim/zirinus-rewrite/main.py", line 132, in spam_event
    message_send_requests = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 115, in post
    return request("post", url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 701, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 489, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 398, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 239, in request
    super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1282, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1323, in _send_request
    self.putheader(hdr, value)
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 224, in putheader
    _HTTPConnection.putheader(self, header, *values)
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1260, in putheader
    raise ValueError('Invalid header value %r' % (values[i],))
ValueError: Invalid header value b'exampletoken123\n'
```

I tried:

Converting to string in dict

I am excepting:

A string object and successful response.

I use Python 3.11.0 with Termux
All packages are up to date.

Comment: The conversion to a `bytes` value is correct (you can't transfer Python `str` objects directly, only an appropriate encoding using ASCII, UTF-8, etc). The problem may be the `\n` you left in the value.

Comment: I did not left \n in my text file.

Comment: Your error message (`b'exampletoken123\n'`) says otherwise. Assuming `token.txt` is a POSIX text file, it ends with a line feed, and `token_file.read()` returns the full contents of the file without removing a trailing line feed.

Comment: why print(auth_token) returns "exampletoken123" ?

Comment: `print` *returns* `None`; it *outputs* the contents of the string, and `\n` is output not as `\n`, but as a literal linefeed (which your terminal interprets as a command to move the cursor to the next line, not a visible glyph).

Comment: How can i specify encoding?

Comment: It's already encoded. `requests` is doing something like `headers["authorization"].encode()` for you. The problem is that something about your actual token makes it invalid. My *guess* is that it's the linefeed. Have you tried `auth_token = token_file.read().rstrip('\n')`?

Comment: You need to strip() out the newline from your token: `token_file.read().strip()`